# POST data from Chrome PostMan plug-in is empty in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, ajax, eclipse, post

I am trying to debug HTTP POST data sent to some AJAX PHP in Eclipse PDT and it is new to me, so I am probably making some very basic mistake.

I found what seems to be an excellent Chrome browser plugin: [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

I have defined my request thus:

[image]

Which is trying to emulate my AngulrJs code (which works)

```
   var postData = { userName: $scope.registrationData.userName,
                    email:    $scope.registrationData.email,
                    password: forge_sha256($scope.registrationData.password)
                  };

   var url = HOST + 'api/register.php';

   $http.post(url, postData)
```

If I just use the AngularJs from a browser page, it works and the PHP returns what I expect it to.

BUT, when I use Postman, then in my PHP code

```
   $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $request = json_decode($postData, true);
```

I find that `$_POST` is empty.

What am I doing wrongly (or is there a simpler way to debug HTTP Post with Eclipse PDT)?

---

[Update] Thanks, @Rubelet, for pointing out that the POST data should go in the body, not the headers.

If I encode it as form data

[image]

the received POST data is still empty. I am guessing that I should use "raw", but how do I encode? As JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are embedding your data in the `Header` section of PostMan. These are for [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and not what you want. When using angular's post method, the parameters are in fact embedded into the Body section of a POST request.

Put your parameters in the `Body` section of Postman and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sure that you are correct. I have been coding for 14 hours and my head is spinning! Please see the update to the question & let know if you cab help furthe

Comment: @Mawg try x-www-form-urlencoded
What you want to check is if your client is behaving as expect. If you are running your angular client in the browser(i hope so) then you can use something like Chrome dev tools to check that your code is sending the correct request. Check this in the network tab

Comment: Yes!!!! You, sir, are a genius (and I am going to bed now :-)  Thanks again